# Why do Gitlab Runner find the script?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

> I want to run shell script in gitlab runner.
> The CI/CD script looks like this
> https://gitlab.com/steinKo/ci-cd-gitlab/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml

> The scripts that should be runn looks like this
> https://gitlab.com/steinKo/ci-cd-gitlab/-/jobs/1073251600

> When the job is runned. The following log is written
> https://gitlab.com/steinKo/ci-cd-gitlab/-/tree/main/infAsCode/scripts

> Why dose the Gitlab runner not find the file of the script?

Answer (score 0):

The image you are using does not have bash installed. You need to install it in your before_script:

```
  before_script:
    - apk update
    - apk add bash
```

See also this [gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2672)